# How to pass all headers from playwright python?

Tags: python, http-headers, playwright-python

Currently, I can send the user-agent from playwright as well the viewport sizes. But i want to send all the headers informations like `accept, accept_encoding, accept_language,referer, cookies,etc`. I looked about `setExtraHTTPHeaders()` too. Is there any way to send them in playwright python.

```
with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    context = browser.new_context(
                user_agent=agent #agent declared above,
            )
    page = context.new_page()
    response = page.goto("https://www.somewebsite.com/")

    #Doing some work in the website
    page.locator('#some_id').fill("some_text")
    page.press('#another_id', "Enter")

    page.route("**/*", intercept_route)
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer was found when i looked what is inside `dir(context)`. In python, we can use `context.set_extra_http_headers(headers)` to send extra headers informations like `accept, accept-encoding, referrer, accept-language,etc`

Answer (score 1):

`user-agent`, `prefers-colors-scheme`, `accept-language`, and `cookies` can be set with the browser's `new_context`'s arguments `user_agent`, `color_scheme`, `locale`, and `storage_state`, respectively. `referer` can be set with `page.goto`'s argument `referer`. For other less popular headers that's not mentioned in the [documentation](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-browser#browser-new-context), they can be set with `new_context`'s argument `extra_http_headers`. The code can look something similar to

```
context = browser.new_context(
            user_agent=agent,
            color_scheme=r"light",
            locale=r"en-US,en;q=0.9",
            storage_state={cookies: [{}],
            extra_http_headers={}
        )
page = context.new_page()
response = page.goto(r"https://www.somewebsite.com/",
                     referer=r"https://google.com"
        )
```

The same can apply for `browser.new_page()`. To better see what headers your browser sends you can go to similar sites like [this one](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-http-headers-is-my-browser-sending). Hope that helps, good luck.